# Segmentation fault when sudo su or other sudo commands

Tags: sudo, nextcloud

I wanted to update my SSL certs on my Pi 3B+ which is running NextcloudPi.
I did not touch the Raspbian System on it for at least 2 months. I am the only one who is able to login.

I connect via SSH using XFCE Terminal on Manjaro:

```
ssh pi@192.168.178.23
```

Login works perfectly, but if then I try to use

```
sudo su
sudo apt-get update
```

and many more I get `Segmentation fault` as error.

Commands like `sudo vi /etc/...default.conf` do actually work.
Like already mentioned, I did not even access the Pi for 2 months or longer, and before everything worked just fine.

It is running NextcloudPi on v1.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation fault is a major software error, caused by invalid memory addresses in the code. It is not something you can typically cause as a user through normal fiddling using standard packages . Except in extremely rare cases where it is a bug that is exposed by something you do.

Assuming you are using repository packages and not compiling from source this is most likely a corrupt program somewhere, most commonly SD card corruption either due to age/wear or other failure. In the worst case this could be a binary replaced as an attempted exploit .

I would reimage a new SD card and see if this resolves the issue

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=235594&p=1441196#p1441196